# Where to see the newsletter for subscribers in shopify

Tags: shopify

Where to see all subscribers user list. Who fill and submit the newsletter form in shopify. and where we set the email to notify
[in red border is my subscribers form][1]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/TEhQj.png

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Shopify documentation](https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/promoting-marketing/create-marketing/customer-emails) to know more about how customer list for marketing works in Shopify.

To see the customers who have opted in for email updates, you can see them by going to

Customers -> Accepts Marketing

[image: Customers who Accept Marketing]

Shopify does not provide any built in tools to send emails to those customers. So you can choose any [relevant app](https://apps.shopify.com/search?q=email%20marketing) from Shopify app store that will allow you to send promotional emails to customers who subscribe to your mailing list.